# PGAdmin JSONB Array

Tags: pgadmin

I am trying to create a table with individual codes from the JSON Array element. Here is the JSONB I have:

```json
"resource": { 
{
    "type": [
        {
            "text": "ABC",
            "coding": [
                {
                    "code": "123",
                    "system": "xxx",
                    "display": "ABC",
                    "userSelected": 
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "class": {
        "code": "453",
        "system": "xxx",
        "display": "yyy"
    },
    "period": {
        "end": "datetime1",
        "start": "datetime2"
    },
    "reason": [
        {
            "text": "DMR",
            "coding": [
                {
                    "code": "231",
                    "display": "DMR",
                    "userSelected": 
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "text": "CDR",
            "coding": [
                {
                    "code": "444",
                    "display": "CDR",
                    "userSelected": 
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "text": "RER",
            "coding": [
                {
                    "code": "777",
                    "display": "RER",
                    "userSelected": 
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "status": "unknown",
 
        }
    ]
```

I want this table:

| TypeCode | TypeDisplay | | ClassCode | ClassDisplay | ClassPeriod |  ReasonCode1 | ReasonDisplay1 |
ReasonCode2 | ReasonDisplay2 |  ReasonCode3 | ReasonDisplay3

| 123   | ABC | 453 | YYY | date2  | 231   | DMR  | 444   | CDR  | 777  | RER

I have the following code that extracts typecode to reasondisplay1 but reasoncode2, reasondisplay2, reasoncode3, reasondisplay3 are null. Any suggestions?

```sql
create table myTable as SELECT  
      resource -> 'resource' -> 'type' -> 0 -> 'coding' -> 0 ->> 'code' AS TypeCode, 
      resource -> 'resource' -> 'type' -> 0 -> 'coding' -> 0 ->> 'display' AS TypeDisplay, 
     
      resource -> 'resource' -> 'class' ->> 'code' as ClassCode,
      resource -> 'resource' -> 'class' ->> 'display' as ClassDisplay,
      resource -> 'resource' -> 'period' ->> 'end' as ClassPeriod,
            
  resource -> 'resource' -> 'reason' -> 0 -> 'coding' -> 0 ->> 'code'  AS ReasonCode1, 
  resource -> 'resource' -> 'reason' -> 0 -> 'coding' -> 0 ->> 'display' AS ReasonDisplay1, 
  resource -> 'resource' -> 'reason' -> 0 -> 'coding' -> 1 ->> 'code' AS ReasonCode2, 
  resource -> 'resource' -> 'reason' -> 0 -> 'coding' -> 1 ->> 'display' AS ReasonDisplay2,
  resource -> 'resource' -> 'reason' -> 0 -> 'coding' -> 2 ->> 'code' AS Reasoncode3, 
  resource -> 'resource' -> 'reason' -> 0 -> 'coding' -> 2 ->> 'display' AS ReasonDisplay3,
  resource -> 'resource' -> 'reason' -> 0 -> 'coding' -> 3 ->> 'code' AS ReasonCode4, 
  resource -> 'resource' -> 'reason' -> 0 -> 'coding' -> 3 ->> 'display' AS ReasonDisplay4
FROM    SourceTable`
```